# Using jquery or javascript to show table only in iframe but also hide certain columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have placed an iframe into a div, i know it is possible for me to display ONLY the table of data i require and hide the rest of the page, but i need to remove columns from the table as well is this possible with jquery? the data is held in doms??? so was hoping there is a small possibility.

Thanks for your comments and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you want to remove specific table columns right?

```
$('table tr').each(
    function(tr_idx,el){
        $(el).children('td').each(
            function(td_idx,el2){
                //i'm removing first columns..
                if(td_idx == 0){
                    el2.remove();
                }
        });//inner each
});//outer each
```

Comment: hey hgoz, thanks for the reply, excellent stuff its 3 in the morning here will give it a bash tomo let you know how it goes

Comment: is it possible to get the iframe to pull show the table only... like you can with divs?

Comment: how dow you remove move the one column or row?